# "Do my work for me" type of questions - how to react?

Tags: discussion

Lately, I came a cross a series of questions:

- [Detecting object person in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418047/detecting-object-person-in-an-image)
- [Seperating Background and Foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423615/seperating-background-and-foreground)
- [Detecting face points in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435445/detecting-face-points-in-an-image)

All from the same user.

While each of these questions can be considered as "legitimate" on its own, considering all of them together they amount into "do my work for me".

They show little effort apart from slicing a big problem into several sub-problems.

**My question:**

How should we react to such behavior?

PS, 
I do not know what tags are appropriate for this post - so please feel free to suggest tags.

Comment: Your third link is the same as the first one?

Comment: @Bart - corrected. thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra - this is not the same question. while there the post discusses questions that are simple RTFM-like, this case is different. This user's questions are interesting and should be considered if they were "stand alone" but the problem here is the **context** of several questions leading SO users to do this person's work for him - which I feel is problematic.

Comment: In this case the questions do appear very specific and localized. Do you feel that they are likely to be of any help to others?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want us to answer your question for you? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It entirely depends on the type of question.

If the question is of the type

> I want to have a project, where user should login(Check usernam,
>   password), then a session is created, user performs some action,
>   access database, store values and blah blah. Please provide me with the code for
>   this.

Then it is okay to give them a downvote and a comment asking them to *research before asking*.

and if the questions are of type,

> I am working on a project, where user should login(Check usernam,
>   password), then a session is created, user performs some action,
>   access database, store values and blah blah. I am done with login and session part, but I dont know how to store values, so as to use them throughout. Please provide me with some 
>   guidance over it.

This type of question could be somehow answered or even can be commented with some links guiding them to the right direction. In this case maybe with a link to the Shared Preferences(Android though).

So its upon you that how you handle the question. ***Gimme the Code*** type of questions are not encouraged, so you can always ask them to research before asking.